# Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string' error with iFrame

Tags: angular

I am trying to print a pdf file with angular but I am having an error on 'iframe.src' line-
This is the error: `Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

```ts
    this.myService.printPages(shareFilter)
    .subscribe((result: any) => {

      const pdf = new Blob([result], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdf);
      const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.style.display = 'none';
      iframe.src = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL, this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(blobUrl));
      document.body.appendChild(iframe);
      iframe.contentWindow.print();
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming `this.sanitizer` is an instance of [`DomSantitizer`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)) `this.sanitizer.sanitize()` has as [return type `string | null`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#sanitize), i.e. may return a `string` or `null`. Whereas [`iframe.src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-src) expects a `string` to be assigned.

With [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) enabled in your `tsconfig.json` this will cause the error you're experiencing because you're trying to assign a (return) value that could possibly be `null` to a property that must be a `string`.

To address this error you must ensure that the value you're assigning to `iframe.src` is not `null`, e.g. by checking it before and assigning a default value in case it is `null`.

A nice shorthand for such a check is the [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

```ts
const url = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL, this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(blobUrl));
iframe.src = url ?? '';
```

For readability the return value of `this.sanitizer.sanitize()` is first assigned to `url` which may be a `string` or `null`.
The expression `url ?? ''` will evaluate to `url` *if* it is a `string`/not `null` and to the empty string (`''`) in case it *is* `null`.